# уменьшение размера изображения с сохранением dpi pygame

Tags: python, изображения, pygame, pillow, обработка-изображений

Сделал векторную клавиатуру в Adobe Illustrator. Экспортировал каждую кнопку в PNG, поставил 300 dpi, все четко, но размер изображения велик. Если я пытаюсь сжать изображение оно мыльное. Задача вставить изображение хорошего качества, но маленького размера в окно pygame. Меня устраивает качество в иллюстраторе, но как только я экспортирую под нужный размер, все кнопки плывут.

[image: клавиатура в Adobe illustrator]

[image: пример мыльной кнопки в окне pygame]

Comment: экспортируйте в нужный размер без antialiasing'а.

Comment: как это сделать?

Comment: выбрать в опциях при экспорте в png